# Parallels Desktop 9 - wifi on Windows 7 VM

Tags: wifi, parallels-desktop

Parallels Desktop enables internet connection on your VM by sharing your current Mac's connection via ethernet-like network.

I want to access on my Windows VM wifi connection, not get it from Mac but to actually connect on it's own - how to do that if there's no wireless adapter device nor wireless icon in taskbar?

Comment: Both Parallels and VMware abstract the hardware so your Mac OS truly controls the hardware. Depending on what the goal of using WiFi - there might be easy solutions like enabling it on the Mac as secondary and setting bridge mode on the virtual/software  network switch Parallels operates.

Answer (score 1):

In Parallels you have a few choices of how to connect to a Network or Internet, [Shared Networking](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22247.htm), [Bridged Ethernet Networking](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22251.htm) and [Host-Only Networking](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22243.htm).  In all of these the Guest OS/VM only sees a Wired Ethernet Adapter as that is what the software provides.  It does not provide a Wi-Fi Network Adapter even though the Guest OS/VM can connect to a Network or Internet using Shared Networking or Bridged Ethernet Networking (which can be bridged to the Host's Wi-Fi or Ethernet adapters) and does not show a Wi-Fi icon in e.g. the Windows Taskbar System Notification Area.  So even following the directions in [Using WiFi in a Virtual Machine](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/27334.htm) which uses Bridged Ethernet Networking the connection in the Guest OS/VM will still appear as a Wired Ethernet Connection.

If you want to have **direct Wi-Fi connectivity in the VM**, *in other words have a Wi-Fi icon in e.g. the Windows Taskbar System Notification Area* as if the virtual machine was a physical machine that had a built-in Wi-Fi Network Adapter, then you will need to supply your own USB Wi-Fi Adapter and connect it directly to the VM.  In this scenario there is no other way!